# Display popup with links that when clicked target self

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, allow-modals

I am making a dashboard with widgets. I want to be able to have a user click somewhere on the widget and a popup to appear (results in the popup will be available reports generated using a SQL query).

When the popup shows choices (different reports) I want user to be able to click on one of the links to the report and the report to become the content (fill) the widget (target="_self").

I have put an iframe inside the widgets to separate the popup content from the page itself.

I explored jQuery, JavaScript, and Bootstrap Modals thus far with some success, but the main issue I am having is targeting self, or parent, to get the link to close the popup/modal and fill the widget the popup originated from.

I cannot use server side technologies like PHP, etc. It needs to be client side.

The old school way used to be `javascript:passBack`:

`<a href="javascript:passBack('1','Dulles, John');">Customer 1</a><br />`

That (passBack) is not working anymore...

Comment: Calling JavaScript code, targeting iframes? No idea what you are talking about. The javascript will execute a function. I am thinking you need to show more code.

Comment: I need a JavaScript/jQuery function that will display links, then when you click on one of the links the content of the link will display (replace) where the links were...

Comment: okay so what have you tried? Can we see code that does not work?

Comment: Bootstrap Modal but the button you clicked on to see the modal stays on the page and is not replaced.

Comment: So you remove the old one.

Comment: JavaScript using Parent.html and Popup.html but code is not cross-browser.

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the actual code....

Comment: jQuery load() method but the popup links are not replaced.

Comment: '$("body").on("click", ".show_modal_w div[data-id]", function() {

  $("input[name='menu_image_id']").val($(this).data("id"));
  $(".show_modal_w").modal("hide");
});
'
This is the code that is close, but I need it to replace the content (target self or target parent)

Comment: This is close to what I am looking to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/f9urohoo/

Comment: When you click on the page it displays a list. Then when you click on one of the links the modal closes and the content is displayed. But I need the content to completely replace the modal on the page, so if you click on the page again only the content is there and the modal is gone..